# IE8 checkbox and radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How Is possible to style checkbox and radio inputs in order to look uniform on all browsers (IE8, firefox,webkit etc). I tried various methods but till now nothing.
I just want to style checkbox and radio not label or a span how I have seen in other web examples.
A little bit help here will be very awesome.
here is a fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/FKRaX/11/

Thank you.

Comment: Your example shows filters which Microsoft has dropped in IE and are non-standard so they don't work in any other browser.

Answer (score 1):

You will need 3d-party JS libraries, like the ones listed here: http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons

Pure CSS solutions will work only in webkit browsers, and might work in latest Firefox. But for IE8 you definitely need to use some JS/jQuery plugins to achieve this.

Comment: And what do you think jQuery sets? CSS.

Comment: Yes I know, is not a problem that... but I don't want to use label for background change or other solutions that involve label, I just want to style only checkbox and radion.

Answer (score 0):

You tried:

file.css:

```
.checkbox {
margin:15px;
/*opacity:0;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);*/
}
```

file.html

```
<input id="pushon" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" />
<input id="pushon" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="checkbox" />
<input id="pushon" type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" class="checkbox" />
<input id="roundon" type="radio" value="Valoare" checked="checked"/>
<input id="roundon" type="radio" value="Valoare" disabled="disabled"/>
<input id="roundon" type="radio" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For older IEs 8, 7, etc you may need to get creative:

E.g.

```
input[type="checkbox"],
#checkboxFieldsID,
.checkboxFieldsClass {
display:inline-block;
-ms-transform: scale(3); /* IE */
-moz-transform: scale(3); /* FF */
-webkit-transform: scale(3); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(3); /* Opera */
padding: 10px;
```

/* tricks for older IEs */

```
background:#40668C; /* trick for older IEs */
width:50px; /* trick for older IEs */
height:50px; /* trick for older IEs */****
}
```